# Signed in status not shared across apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have 2 RoR websites that used to be able to share signed in status for the current user.  In `config/initializers/session_store.rb` I've added the following:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, 
    key: '_website_session', 
    domain: :all
```

My 2 websites are located at `v1.xyz.com` and `clients.xyz.com` and so they should be able to share signed in status, however when I sign in at `clients.xyz.com` and open `v1.xyz.com`, I'm not signed in.

I've also set the `after_sign_in_path_for` in `v1.xyz.com` to `clients.xyz.com/profile` so I can't seem to access `v1.xyz.com` as a signed in user.

What am I missing to allow the session to be stored accross both websites?

Answer (score 0):

Your cookies are encrypted by your apps secret_key_base, so if u have different keys u cant share session

Comment: Where would I find that variable?  The `secret_key` in Devise is the same.  Not sure where this variable would be referenced